# MySQL always returning BIT values as blank

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

From my create table script, I've defined the hasMultipleColors field as a BIT:

```
hasMultipleColors BIT NOT NULL,
```

When running an INSERT, there are no warnings thrown for this or the other BIT fields, but selecting the rows shows that all BIT values are blank.

Manually trying to UPDATE these records from the command line gives odd effect - shows that the record was match and changed (if appropriate), but still always shows blank.

Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

```
mysql> update pumps set hasMultipleColors = 1 where id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select hasMultipleColors from pumps where id = 1;
+-------------------+
| hasMultipleColors |
+-------------------+
|                  |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update pumps set hasMultipleColors = b'0' where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select hasMultipleColors from pumps where id = 1;
+-------------------+
| hasMultipleColors |
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why aren't you using `BOOL` instead of `BIT` for that? From the semantics of your field name, it'd make more sense.

Comment: Did some reading regarding the BOOL vs. BIT vs. TINYINT data-types, and the take-away I took was that MySQL handles BOOL in a very poor manner - not portable to other RDBMS solutions - so it's generally ideal to go with TINYINT or BIT (more efficient).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to cast the bit field to an integer.

```
mysql> select hasMultipleColors+0 from pumps where id = 1;
```

This is because of a bug, see: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43670. The status says: Won't fix.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  So this is just an issue of display rather than data being properly captured and stored.  Any way to automatically cast bit datatypes when using a * in select?

Comment: I have a very weird version of this, where in the first case, the BIT fields display with no problem. But then in a different table, where the BIT fields are defined just like in the first table, nothing prints unless I do something like add 0 to each BIT column. If this is a bug, then why is it just working in the first case but not the second? TL:DR to give the gory details. One other weirdness: while this problem occurs in the mysql client on my server, the client built into my IDE (PHPStorm) does not have the problem at all, and just works with BIT fields.

Comment: @RTB there is a simple solution to this problem and I added it.

Answer (score 8):

You can cast BIT field to unsigned.

```
  SELECT CAST(hasMultipleColors AS UNSIGNED) AS hasMultipleColors 
  FROM pumps 
  WHERE id = 1
```

It will return 1 or 0 based on the value of `hasMultipleColors`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to perform a conversion as `bit 1` is not printable.

`SELECT hasMultipleColors+0 from pumps where id = 1;`

See more here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason for the effect you see, is that it's done right and as expected.

The `bit` field has bits and thus return bits, and trying to output a single bit as a character will show the character with the given bit-value – in this case a zero-width control character.

Some software may handle this automagically, but for command line MySQL you'll have to cast it as int in some way (e.g. by adding zero).

In languages like PHP the ordinal value of the character will give you the right value, using the `ord()` function (though to be really proper, it would have to be converted from decimal to binary string, to work for bit fields longer than one character).

**EDIT:**
Found a quite old source saying that it changed, so a MySQL upgrade might make everything work more as expected: http://gphemsley.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/php-mysql-and-the-bit-field-type/